# Crontab only for 24 hours, but every 4 hours

Tags: cron

How can I run a crontab for every 4 hours where I download a file from a certain given link but only for 24 hours, starting at midnight? And put the 8 file content in a new file?

Answer (score 1):

I recommend using `at`, not `cron`, because that way you won't have to remember to remove the crontab entry when the 24 hours are up. Just schedule 8 identical `at` jobs to run at the desired times (each 4 hours apart). In each job, you can, for example, use `curl` or `wget`, but of which can easily support writing the downloaded contents wherever you want it.

Comment: if I use cron, is there a command I can do to automatically stop it an remove the entry after 24 hours are up and move the 8 results into a new file?

Comment: No. That's not what `cron` does. That's the difference between `cron` and `at`. Why do you *have* to use cron??

Comment: Wouldn't it be less efficient to create 8 different at jobs though? and i'm doing an old practice exam and it said it had to be a cron job

Comment: I don't see what would be that inefficient about creating 8 `at` jobs. But otherwise, if you really want, you can certainly write a script that runs through `cron` and contains a conditional to either do something or nothing depending on a flag of some kind.